# Find $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{2\arcsin x - \pi}{\sin(\pi x)}.$

Tags: calculus

My solution:
\begin{align*}
& \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{2\arcsin x - \pi}{\sin(\pi x)} = \left|\frac{2\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi}{0}\right| \\
    & \stackrel{\mathrm{L'H.}}{=}  \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\pi \cos(\pi x)} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2}{\pi \cos{\pi x}\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align*}
We find the left limit:
\begin{align*}
& \lim_{\substack{x \to 1-\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon \to 0}} \frac{2}{\pi \cos(\pi x)\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{2}{\pi \cos(\pi (1-\varepsilon))\sqrt{1-(1-\varepsilon)^2}}\\
    &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{2}{\pi \cos(\pi (1-\varepsilon))} \cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-\varepsilon)^2}} \\
    & = -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-\varepsilon)^2}} \\
    &= -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon(2-\varepsilon)}} \\
    &= -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\varepsilon}} \cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \\
    &= -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \infty = -\infty
\end{align*}
Right:
\begin{align*}
& \lim_{\substack{x \to 1+\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon \to 0}} \frac{2}{\pi \cos(\pi x)\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{2}{\pi \cos(\pi (1+ \varepsilon))\sqrt{1-(1+\varepsilon)^2}} \\
    &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{2}{\pi \cos(\pi (1+\varepsilon))} \cdot \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1+\varepsilon)^2}} = -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot  \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1+\varepsilon)^2}} \\
    &=  -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot  \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2}} = -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot  \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(-1)(2\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2)}} \\
    &= -\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot i \infty = (-i) \infty.
\end{align*}
My question is: are my steps correct at the right side for example we have an $i$, but we haven't work with complex numbers (at our school).

Comment: What is your actual question?  For the original limit, it only makes sense from the left since (at least if you're working in the real case), the domain of $\arcsin$ is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+approaches+1+of+(2arcsin(x)-pi)%2Fsin(pi*x)) says your answer for the right side should have been $i\infty$. This is because from your second limit, you should've gotten $\frac{\infty}{i}=(-i)\infty$ and then the negative from both limits cancel.

Comment: Also, your use of $\infty$ is dangerous, for example, you should never write "$=\frac{0}{0}$" since that is indeterminate.  Also, you can't break up a product of limits unless both the limits exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $x$ must be $\le1$  for real $\arcsin(x)$

Let $1-x=y\iff x=1-y$

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{2\arcsin x - \pi}{\sin(\pi x)} =-2\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\arccos(1-y)}{\sin\pi y}$$

Now $\arccos(1-y)=\arcsin\sqrt{1-(1-y)^2}=\arcsin\sqrt{2y-y^2}$

$$\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\arccos(1-y)}{\sin\pi y}=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\arcsin\sqrt{2y-y^2}}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}\cdot\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac y{\sin\pi y}\cdot\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}y$$

$$=\dfrac1\pi\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}y=?$$

Comment: May be you skipped a $\pi$ in the second step while evaluating the limit. $$\sin(\pi x) = \sin(\pi-\pi y) = \sin(\pi y)$$

Comment: @Aritra, agreed

Answer (score 0):

We have the following:

$$-\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot  \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(-1)(2\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2)}} $$

Factor out a $\frac{1}{i}$ from the limit:
$$-\frac{2}{\pi} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{i\sqrt{(2\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2)}} $$

Now, the limit is clearly $\frac{\infty}{i}=-i\infty$, so we get:
$$-\frac 2 \pi \cdot -i\infty=i\infty$$